# Divide does nothing

Tags: sql, db2

I'm attempting to create percentile scores. My query generates the ranks correctly, but the divide does nothing(the ranks are displayed in the columns rather than scores)

```
"/"(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "Disk IO"),Count(*)) "Disk IO Score"
```

I've also tried generating the rank then selecting that and dividing, but it has the same result.

```
SELECT ..."/"("Disk IO Score",Count(*)) "Score"...
FROM(....RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "Disk IO") "Disk IO Score"...)
```

Thanks,
Buzkie

```
SELECT "System_Name", "/"(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "Disk IO"),Count(*)) "Disk IO Score" 
FROM (Select...)
GROUP BY "System_Name", "Disk IO"
```

Comment: What do your `COUNT(*)s` return?

Comment: Good Question. Returning 1, which makes sense from the results, but not desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's answered. The count(*) was returning 1 so I was just dividing by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using aggregate `COUNT(*)` rather than analytic one.

Try this:

```
SELECT  RANK() OVER (...) / COUNT(*) OVER (...)
```

And could you please post the whole query (including `GROUP BY` clauses)?

Comment: I think I've figured out the problem. The counts are returning the number of instances of each server which is 1 due to the grouping. Can you think of a way that I could get the count of all the servers?

Comment: It's hard to tell with all your obfuscations. What is the server?